# Asp.net controller recieving null

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, post

My ASP.net controller is receiving null instead of passed in parameters :(
Js function:

```
function SendFormToController() {
            var username = document.getElementById("UsernameField").value;
            var email = document.getElementById("EmailField").value;
            var password = document.getElementById("PasswordField").value;

            var SendJson = {
                Username: username,
                Email: email,
                Password: password
            };
            console.log(JSON.stringify(SendJson));
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(SendJson),
                url: "Register/Register",
                contentType: "application/json"
            });
        }
```

Data is present when I console log it. But in the controller, I get - https://prnt.sc/u2mpa6
And it is for every field here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First; Did you add the `[HttpPost]` attribute on top of your controller method?

Second; If you submit it in 'querystring' format: Username=xx&Password=yy&... and use (HttpGet). Does that work?

If you need to do a POST (and not want to use GET) you can create an object with all your current arguments and use the `[FromBody]` attribute:

```
[Route("Register")]
[HttpPost]
public ResultData Register([FromBody] RegisterRequest data) {
   //Your logic...
}
```

And client (JavaScript) side:

```
let url = 'http://...';
$.post(url, { Username: name, Password: pass, What: ever  }, function (result) {
    //Do some nice stuff
})
.fail(function (error) {
    //Oh no! Show error.statusText
});
```

Comment: Nop. I haven't added [HttpPost] On top of the controller. If I submit in a regular way, then yea. It receives everything

Comment: Added [HttpPost] still null

Comment: Ok. Change to [HttpGet] and try to submit via url. e.g.: "Register/Register?username=xx&..." and use $.getJSON() or so.

Comment: Apparently, if I input parameters manually, they get recognised by the controller. But if I do it with Ajax, no luck. Receives null still. It does not matter if get or post

Comment: Ok, can you post your Javascript? or just try this:

 $.getJSON("Register/Register?username=xx&...", function (result) {
                    //do something
                })
                .fail(function () {
                    console.log("error");
                });

So do not specify: stringify, type and contenttype

Comment: https://prnt.sc/u2n17a This one apparently works. And it receives all the parameters

Comment: But I need post anyways :D And not constant parameters though

Comment: Ok, great to know that works! So there is nothing wrong here! :)

Comment: To use post: [HttpPost] add a [Route] and you can create an object as argument [FromBody] and client side:
$.post(url, { Username: name }, function(result) {  });

Comment: I've updated my answer,.. hope that helps. If so, please accept. Thx